# MITM Proxy - How to intercept user requests in reverse proxy mode from inside/outside Web Application Server

Tags: reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I am new to mitm.
https://mitmproxy.org/

AppServer1 (A windows 2016 server) has our IIS website application (WebApp1) running (its running fine without any problems currently).
I have added an SSL certificate as well, and it is loading fine without any issues.Chrome shows that it is trusted ("Connection is secure" when navigating from inside and outside AppServer1 server but "within the LAN". So far we havnt allowed access to internet users as of yet until the app is completely ready.)

We have a business requirement where

- we need to intercept all traffic/requests from users from outide AppServer1
- and send them to another application that we created (UserRequestDashboardApp),
- and ALSO we need mitm to send it to WebApp1 as well.

I have read the articles multiple times and from what I understand, reverse proxy mode is the correct option to for our requirement.

WebApp1 is running on url - customappservice1.com, port - 443

I then started mitm (version 4.0.4) with the following CMD command

```
.\mitmdump -p 8080 --mode reverse:https://customappservice1.com
```

**I get the status proxy server listening at http://*:8080**

I dont seem to see any traffic in the terminal when I type customappservice1.com on AppServer1 chrome browser or any server browser outside AppServer1.
The WebApp1 pages load fine from outside and inside AppServer1 server but **no traffic at all on the terminal**

Can anyone please help me to capture the traffic on the terminal as an initial step before sending the traffic/requests to UserRequestDashboardApp AND WebApp1?

I have tried running mitm normally and it works fine(I can see traffic/requests fine in the terminal)

- I launched mitm in CMD (It says **Proxy Server listening at http://*:8080**)
- I set the

  - Windows server proxy to = localhost
  - Port = 8080

Comment: Have you adapted the external DNS entries to point to the server where mitmproxy is running? Otherwise no one will use mitmproxy and directly connect to the server. Note that in reverse mode with HTTPS you have to equip mitmproxy with the server certificate. But IMHO mitmproxy is the wrong software for logging requests on a productive system. The common way would be e.g. using NGINX for SSL/TLS  Termination.

Comment: Hi @Robert Thanks so muchfor your tip about the certificate. The MITM website said nothing about having to use a .pem cert with the reverse proxy. I tried this on new command **mitmdump -p 8080 --mode reverse:http://localhost/ --listen-host 0.0.0.0 --certs *=customappservice1.pem** I then pointed an external server's (server2) hostfile to point to AppServer1  when I type **customappservice1.com** on the browser. When I navigate from server2 I get an error saying **Not Found. HTTP Error 404. The request source is not found**.But theCMD terminal shows **GET http://localhost/ <<404 not found 315b

Comment: @Robert ...continued. [link](https://ibb.co/93sYDF4). Is there anyway for me to now send the requests received to WebApp1 so we dont see the **Not Found. HTTP Error 404. The request source is not found.** error on server2 web browser. THANKS VERY MUCH for your help so far its is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try configuring your requests to use the mitmproxy's address ?

Also, web browsers may have use a separate proxy configuration from the operating system's. So you may try configuring Chrome's proxy settings.